# League\Flysystem\Exception Impossible to create the root directory

Tags: php, laravel

I have an application in laravel. And I try to open a pdf file.

So my domain of the application is this: http://intranet.wbg.local/

And I have the application in this folder: C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel

And the url for the pdf is this:

```
http://intranet.wbg.local/vt/boek/merge
```

And I have this function:

```
    public function merge()
    {
        $files = glob('http://intranet.wbg.local/html/public/pdf/*.pdf');
        $merger = new Merger;
        foreach ($files as $pdf) {
            $merger->addFile($pdf);
        }
        $createdPdf = $merger->merge();
        \Storage::put(public_path() . '/pdf/a.pdf', $createdPdf);
        file_put_contents(public_path() . '/pdf/a.pdf', $createdPdf);
        die('done');
    }
```

But when I enter the url:

```
http://intranet.wbg.local/vt/boek/merge
```

I get this error:

```
League\Flysystem\Exception
Impossible to create the root directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\storage\app\C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public/pdf".
http://intranet.wbg.local/vt/boek/merge
```

So what I have to change?

Thank you

I get this error:

```
Impossible to create the root directory "C:\xampp\htdocs\laravel\storage\app\C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/public/pdf".
```

if I change this:

```
$files = glob('C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/html/public/pdf/*.pdf');
```

Comment: Don't use a "remote" URL but the path of the file/folder instead

Comment: Yes, oke, So I changed to this:   $files = glob('C:/xampp/htdocs/laravel/html/public/pdf/*.pdf'); but I get the same error

Comment: Make sure there are actually files in that folder (where does `/html` come from??). Read about [File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/master/filesystem) (Probably need to remove the `public_path()`). Why do you `\Storage::put()` _AND_ `file_put_contents()`?